# Primefaces and Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, primefaces

Within my UI I have some javascript:

```
<ui:define name="myheaderIncludes">
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function sayhi() {
            alert('hi');
  }
    </script>  
</ui:define>
```

From the form, I'm using a dialog form to pop up for file import.

```
<p:dialog id="abc" header="Import" widgetVar="dlgabc" modal="false" 
              height="125" width="580" appendToBody="true" hideEffect="fade">
```

I'm trying th call the javascript from the dialog form - to test I added a button:

```
<p:button value="Test" id="start" type="button" onclick="sayhi();"  widgetVar="startButton1"/>
```

For whatever reason, the sayhi() does NOT get called.  Any thoughts/comments?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a context where you inserted defined javascript? Did you saw any errors in javascript console?

Comment: Edit your question and post your code there. Comments are not appropriate for that.

Comment: @partlov - thanks for the help.  Your comment "show a context where you inserted defined javascript" pointed me in the right direction!  I moved it into my "content" section, and it worked as expected.  Thanks again!